# Behaviour of crontab -e and environmental variables or configuration of default editor ( Debian )

Tags: debian, configuration, environment-variables, editors, settings

*Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-17-amd64
Architecture: x86-64*

I am studying behavior of `crontab -e`. Are following assumptions correct?

1. `crontab -e` edits the crontab file in "default editor"
2. Such "default editor" is selected by `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`
3. If `printenv EDITOR` returns blank, the above "default editor" is used
4. But if `$EDITOR` is defined, it takes precedence over the "default editor"

Also, after selecting "default editor", where is that selection stored? Many online resource explains *how* to select "default editor", but I couldn't find answer to location of configuration file.

Comment: You have to add this ***setting*** into your personal `.profile` file (then logout and relog) or `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man crontab` answers most of your questions; if you’re using [Vixie Cron](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/cron/crontab.1):

> The `-e` option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables. After you exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed automatically. If neither of the environment variables is defined, then the default editor `/usr/bin/editor` is used.

So the editor is determined by the `VISUAL` variable, or if it’s not set, the `EDITOR` variable, and if that’s not set, `/usr/bin/editor`. The latter is an alternative, *i.e.* a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/editor`, which is itself a symlink to the chosen editor, configurable as you say by running `update-alternatives`.

That’s how the chosen alternative is stored: the corresponding symlink is updated. Information about alternatives is also stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`. See [`man update-alternatives`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/dpkg/update-alternatives.1) for details.